# Remote Docker Visual Studio Code - No running containers - Mac OS

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, visual-studio-container-tools

I am trying to Attach VS Code Window into a Docker container inside my remote machine on Azure.
It has stopped working at some point, the message is "There are no running container to attach to", but clearly there is one because it finds it in the Docker extensions.

These are my steps.

1. Open VS Code
2. SSH-Remote Development to open VS Code on the Remote machine and install Docker extension there
3. I find the docker container in the remote machine, but it fails opening it.

I attach here a screenshot.

[image]

I have tried this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1116) of possibly being because of opening VS Code from Spotlight instead of the Terminal, but is not the case.

Thanks !

Comment: did you fidn the answer? i have a similar issue

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but opening a folder first, on the VSCode instance on the remote machine, seems to solve the problem for me.

- File > Open Folder > "chose a folder"

Comment: It is incredibly silly that you have to do this. It does work though

Comment: @miversen33 somehow, it works on my machine